# Can't import webform settings after creating / testing a form

Tags: webforms

On server I already have site setup with webform module installed. If I i.e. create and test some webform and after that try to import webform configuration with `drush cim` I get error:

"*There are entities of the type Webform submission  and  Webform  Kontakt form  These entities must be deleted before importing*".

That issue is also reported here:
https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/3076341
But I didn't find solution for it yet.

And by: https://www.jrockowitz.com/blog/managing-webform-configuration
Webforms should be configuration entities.

So any idea why is this happening and how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing sounds inevitable to me.

You've created a configuration entity (webform), you haven't exported it, and now you're running a config import. Drupal is syncing your config, so correctly tries to delete the webform because it isn't in the config you've told it to import.

The webform however has submissions, so can't be deleted, hence the error message.

Available solutions are:

1. Export the config for your new webform before trying the config import again.
2. Delete the submissions so the webform can be deleted by the import.
3. Add a suitable [config ignore](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_ignore) pattern so your work-in-progress webforms aren't considered during config imports